# Can my NPM CLI package be executed on CMD without installing globally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npx, package-development

I have written an NPM package which has its own CLI commands.

Let's name that package as `xyz` and imagine it's now avaialable on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/)

So, let's say a user installs this package in his project by running `npm install xyz`.

And now he wants to run a CLI command provided by `xyz` package on his terminal in his project.

`xyz do_this`

Can this be done without installing this package globally by user ? Or without any further configuration for the user ?

Here's some part of the `package.json` of the xyz package.

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Description",
  "main": "index.js",
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "bin": "./index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
........
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how npm works. When you install a package in the local directory, it installs the executable dependencies files inside node_modules inside the folder with package.json, but if you use `--global`, it places it globally where the user has set their path.
For example, when I run `npm install http-server`, my executable ends up as `./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server` but when I install it globally, I have it as `node_modules/http-server/bin`

The work around for this is, if you want to just run the executable, just execute it inside like so `./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server`. If you want it as a command, you'll need to have the user add the directory to their Path so when the user enters the command, the computer looks for the command inside that folder.
Here's a guide to adding PATH directories in Linux, you'll just add the directory `/pathtofolder/node_modules/http-server/bin/` or whatever your folder is. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-directory-to-path-in-linux/

For example, if I wanted to add `http-server` from my local folder to my path, I would run

`export PATH="/pathtofolder/node_modules/http-server/bin/:$PATH"`

Good luck! Let me know how I can help you!

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, if I want it as a command, either user has to update the PATH or install it globally ? And If he's calling it from inside the project folder, he needs to run the command like ```./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server``` ? I hope I got it clear.

Comment: Since, I want it as a command, like ```sequelize db:migrate```, I should mention in the package README, that the user needs to install it globally right ? Otherwise it's not a convenient command for the user to update his PATH or call it with the full path.

Comment: That's correct, you wouldn't want to have the user manually add it to the path, it's really complex and not useful. Having a user just run `npm install --global xyz` would probably be the best solution.
I hoped this helped! If you think my solution was the correct one, feel free to accept my answer as the solution by pressing the big check mark next to the solution icon! :)

Comment: Hi Tharindu! I know it's been a long time but I just found something. You can run command line packages without installing it globally. There are 2 more ways. First, install `npm install -g npx` and then run `npx <command>` that is in the node_modules. That will try to run it. Another way is to run a script inside package.json just be referencing it like `http-server`, no global flag needed. Good luck!

Comment: @KylerChin you should add this as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, as also given in the comment above, is to install the needed package locally like

```
$ node install [@<scope>/]<package>
```

and run the command later on with npx from same directory

```
$ npx <package/command>
```

We do this in our build systems to avoid global installs and their permission issues.